# Can azure mobile services apns object support silent push/remote notifications

Tags: apple-push-notifications, azure-mobile-services

Adding a `content-available` value to the `payload` parameter of the azure mobile services' `apns` `send` method doesn't seem to have any effect.

- Is that the case ?
- And if so, does that mean remote notifications (i.e. silent pushes) aren't possible via azure mobile services ?

Here's how i'm trying:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {    
    var push = request.service.push;

    push.apns.send('token', { 
        'content-available': 1,
        sound: 0
        // priority: 5,
        // alert: 'value',
        // badge: 1,
        // sound: 'default',
        // payload: {
        //    ...
        //}
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you paste the full line of code you're using to do the push?

Comment: I've edited the question with an example of the code

Answer (score 0):

This should be working for you. Please review the following link for more information to ensure you've also configured your application to receive a silent notification.

http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/

Comment: Hi Todd. Receiving silent notifications on the app is not a problem, for example we can achieve them using azure notification hubs. When you say this should be working are you saying that adding `content-available` to the `payload` parameter should propagate through to the push notification received to the device? (that being exactly what we are not seeing). Thanks

Comment: I just looked at this again. Our design currently mimics the node apn library making it somewhat confusing to use in my opinion. The easiest thing to make this work is to make a string using the full aps formatted payload. In your case, it would be something like following "{'aps': {'content-available':1}, 'payloadmembers': 'payloadcontents' }".

Comment: Can you clarify how I would use that string with the `push.apns.send(deviceToken, payload, options)` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj839711.aspx#send). Thanks

Comment: There are 2 issues that could be in play:
1. If you are using enhanced push, the documentation is not updated. You can use the following document with the exception that the success/error callbacks are folded into the options rather than being their own parameter: http://dl.windowsazure.com/nodedocs/ApnsService.html
2. If you are not using enhanced push (which you can tell by checking the push tab for MPNS if enhanced) then try using the contentAvailable in place if content-Available. (I've recently fixed our wrapper of APN to do this for you, but it is possible you don't yet have this fix.)